# How can I enable one specific tab by clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tabs

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs').tabs();
  $("#btnContinue").click(function() {
    $("#test2").attr("disabled", "false");
  });
});

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="col s12">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
<div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
<div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>

<div class="modal-content" id="test1">
  <h4>Register</h4>
  <p>A bunch of text</p>
  <form id="signup-form">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="email" id="signup-email" required />
      <label for="signup-email">Email address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="password" id="signup-password" required />
      <label for="signup-password">Choose password</label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn yellow darken-2 z-depth-0" id="btnContinue">Continue</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

My idea is that I have 4 tabs and 3 of them are disabled(I used materialize css). If the user enter his Email and his Password and then presses the button, the tab 2 should be enabled(only tab2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code, `disabled` is not attribute/property but `class`, on button click add class `disabled` to all tab but remove from the second tab.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs').tabs();
  
  $("#btnContinue").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // <== disable form submit
    $('.tab').addClass('disabled');
    var secondTab = $('.tab').eq(1)
    secondTab.removeClass('disabled', false)
    secondTab.find('a')[0].click(); // switch tab
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="col s12">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
<div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
<div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>

<div class="modal-content" id="test1">
  <h4>Register</h4>
  <p>A bunch of text</p>
  <form id="signup-form">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="email" id="signup-email" required />
      <label for="signup-email">Email address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="password" id="signup-password" required />
      <label for="signup-password">Choose password</label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn yellow darken-2 z-depth-0" id="btnContinue">Continue</button>
  </form>
</div>
```